# UINavigationController(rootViewController: MyViewController()) triggers viewdidLoad and returns nil navigationController

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I am trying to understand the logic behind initialising a `UINavigationController` using the initialiser:

```
UINavigationController(rootViewController: MyViewController())
```

The app I am modifying used this initialiser and inside `MyViewController` custom initialiser I had:

```
class MyViewController:UIViewController{

    init(){
        super.init(nibName: "MyViewController", bundle: nil)
    }

}
```

Inside the `MyViewController` lifecycle methods, the `viewDidLoad` used to have not `nil` for the `navigationController` value.

The only change I have done is inside the custom initialiser. Now:

```
init(){
    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)

    /*EDIT*/
    let dummyMe = UIView()
    view.addSubview(dummyMe)

}
```

In other words, I don't want to use a xib file. That change got me into a crash and, after some debugging, I realised that the `navigationController` value was nil inside the `viewDidLoad` method but not in my viewWillAppear method.

How is that possible? Should the `UINavigationController` initialiser call `viewDidLoad`? Why is `navigationController` value `nil` now?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should check your code. Example works as expected, you can paste it to playground:

```swift
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class MyViewController:UIViewController{
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print(#function)
        print(navigationController)
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        print(#function)
        print(navigationController)
    }
}

let controller = UINavigationController(rootViewController: MyViewController())
```

this code will not trigger life cycle methods. Add `PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = controller.view` to trigger and see:

```
viewDidLoad()
Optional(<UINavigationController: 0x7ffb18001200>)
viewWillAppear
Optional(<UINavigationController: 0x7ffb18001200>)
```

**UPD:**

to add custom views override `loadView`:

```swift
override func loadView() {
    super.loadView()
    let subviewFrame = view.bounds
    let dummyMe = UIView(frame: subviewFrame)
    dummyMe.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]
    dummyMe.backgroundColor = .yellow
    view.addSubview(dummyMe)
}
```

or even:

```swift
override func loadView() {   
    let dummyMe = UIView()
    dummyMe.backgroundColor = .yellow
    view = dummyMe
}
```

Comment: You are right as my logic was too! However there is something else I did not mentioned in my question. I think i found why viewDidLoad was triggered. Can you have a look at my edited question? Is adding subviews within the initialisation a Bad practise?

Comment: @ReimondHill move your subviews initialization to `loadView`. See updated answer.

Comment: Thank. I was setting up my view (subviews and constraints) inside the constructor but I never realised about this behaviour until now

Comment: @ReimondHill during init you access `view` that was not loaded yet. It will trigger `loadView` -> `viewDidLoad` sequence. So it happened even before `UINavigationController` was inited